# System.out.print doesn't work on JBoss EAP 6/JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss7.x, stdout, jboss-eap-6

I deplyed a very simple war on JBoss EAP 6.0.1. The servlet action is ok,but System.out.print wasn't print to the console and server.log file.But System.out.println is working well,and when System.out.print and System.out.println both used,both work well.
I try the following setting,but still cann't make it work.Please help!

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.logging.Log4jService.catchSystemOut=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false"
```

I try to add jboss-deployment-structure.xml to WEB-INF to use my own log4j,it doesn't work too.I also try to deploy the war on JBoss AS 7/JBoss EAP 6.1.0,get the same result.
It's a bug???

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense that `System.out.println` would work, but `System.out.print` wouldn't. It should be printing to both the console and server.log assuming the default configuration.

The `-Dorg.jboss.logging.Log4jService.catchSystemOut=false` won't do anything since JBoss AS 7 doesn't use log4j. Also the `-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false` only works on EAP 6.x, WildFly or builds off of the JBoss AS 7.1.3+ tags.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But Unfortunately it's really.More stranger is when System.out.print and System.out.println both used,both work well.....My environment is EAP 6.0.1,I always call it JBoss 7,I thought the diffrents is small....On EAP 6.x, default log component isn't log4j too?What the default it use? slf4j?

Comment: `System.out.print("xxx\n")` is ok. Which component is control the System.out's output? I see jboss-logmanager's source,nothing get.It's a bug? or any setting can change that?

Comment: Try a `System.out.print()` followed by a `System.out.println()`. It might be a flushing issue.

Comment: JBoss logging is capturing the System.out.  It most probably buffering the System.out output until a new line is send to put the line in a log statement (in `sdout` logger)